# Cordova backbutton preventDefault is not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova-3, ionic-framework

I have application which is done using ionicframework and cordova. In my app i have requirement that if user pressed back button then i need to ignore it. But only after user pressed it third time it should close app.

Previously project was done using phonegap and jquery and same code works. I did small workaround when i am throwing an exception then it app was not closed when it should not.

```
 document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
        if (new Date() - firstDateClick > 1000) {
            firstDateClick = new Date();
            totalClicks = 1;
        } else {
            totalClicks++;
            if (totalClicks >= 3) {
                var answer = confirm('Are You Sure You Want Exit');
                if (answer) {
                    var service = angular.injector(['ng', 'starter.services']).get('DanceService');
                    service.logEvent("exit")
                        .then(function () {
                            alert('exit1')
                            if (navigator.app) {
                                navigator.app.exitApp();
                            }
                            else if (navigator.device) {
                                navigator.device.exitApp();
                            }

                        })
                } else {
                    totalClicks = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        throw "ignore"
    });
```

But i dont like idea to throw exception.

Comment: I don't see where you are using the preventDefault

Comment: @jcesar i have posted only workaround...

Comment: Anyways, if you listen the backbutton event and create a function no manage it, you don't have to prevent anything. Try adding a third param to the function. document.addEventListener("backbutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made two times control before log out from the app. So the user can press one time and a toast will appear with the text "press again to exit" and the second press -> log out.

This is my service:

```
    var deregisterFunction = null;

    return {
        disableBack: disableBack,
        registerAction: registerAction,
        goHome: goHome,
        goBack: goBack,
        deregisterAction: deregisterAction,
        closeApp: closeApp
    };

    function disableBack() {
        deregisterFunction = angular.copy($ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(null, 101));
    }

    function registerAction(cb, priority) {
        deregisterFunction = angular.copy($ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(cb, priority));
    }

    function deregisterAction() {
        if (deregisterFunction) {
            deregisterFunction();
        }
        goBack();//default behaviour
    }

    function goHome() {
        deregisterFunction = angular.copy($ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function() {
            $state.go('app.home');
        }, 101));
    }

    function goBack() {
        deregisterFunction = angular.copy($ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function() {
            $ionicHistory.goBack();
        }, 101));
    }

    function closeApp() {
        deregisterFunction = angular.copy($ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function() {
            ionic.Platform.exitApp();
        }, 101));
    }
```

And this my utils service:

```
    var service = {
      logoutToast: logoutToast,
      resetToastCount: resetToastCount
    };

    var toastCount = 0;

    return service;

    function resetToastCount() {
      toastCount = 0;
    }

    function logoutToast() {
      switch (toastCount) {
        case 0:
          $cordovaToast.show('Press again to log out', 'short', 'bottom');
          toastCount++;
          break;
        case 1:
          toastCount = 0;
          //logout
          break;
        default:
          $cordovaToast.show('Error', 'short', 'bottom');
      }
    }

}
}());
```

So in my controller i have this for register the action of my service:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', backButtonService.registerAction(utils.logoutToast, 101));
```

This for reset the count where i want:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', utils.resetToastCount());
```

And this for deregister my action when i navigate:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', backButtonService.deregisterAction);
```

Hope this will helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Disable back button on Ionic/Cordova

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(null, 101);
```